# Matlab - Vertical moving lines in Axes GUIDE

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, matlab-guide

I would like to add two vertical moving lines to the graph and depending on their position it would change the values in the boxes `Start` and `End`.

I would also like to do the other way around: by changing the values in the boxes `Start` and `End` it would move the vertical lines to the assigned positions.

[image: plot]

I have this inside the `pushbutton1_Callback`

```
hold on;
plot(x,y);
SP = 20;
line([SP,SP],get(handles.axes1,'Xlim'),'Color','red');
```

I suppose I would have to create callback events for mouseButtonDown and mouseButtonUp, but I am very new to Matlab and don't know what to put in those callbacks

Answer (score 0):

The way around:
by typing values in edit boxes Start and End you can plot verticle lines. In each of these edit boxes (my case edit1 and edit2) callbacks write

EDIT: now old lines are deleted

```
function edit1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
start=str2num(get(hObject, 'string'));
if isfield(handles,'startLine'); delete(handles.startLine); end
handles.startLine=line([start,start],ylim,'Color',[.8 .8 .8]);
guidata(hObject, handles);

function edit2_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
LineEnd=str2num(get(hObject, 'string'));
if isfield(handles,'LineEnd'); delete(handles.LineEnd); end
handles.LineEnd=line([LineEnd,LineEnd],ylim,'Color',[.8 .8 .8]);
guidata(hObject, handles);
```

Comment: Thanks! Now, when I type and hit enter twice in `Start` or in `End` it writes two lines, but I would like to delete the first one and just show the second.